# ImportError: No module named pillow

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to work with [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.3.x/index.html#) on a Mac OS X Pro, where I did the following:

```
from pillow import Image
```

However, I got the this error:

```
ImportError: No module named pillow
```

When I try to install pillow as follow:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pillow)
```

I'm not sure what to do at this point. I have pillow installed, but not able to import it.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `from PIL import Image` that's how you should call it

Comment: yes. Pillow is a for of the original PIL library (which became unmaintained). The fork got this name (pillow) to distinguish the two, but the usage is essentially the same, thus, you would also import it via `from PIL import Image`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package name is called `pillow` but `Python Image Library` is used as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
#Read image
im = Image.open( 'image.jpg' )
#Display image
im.show()
```

`PIL` was the old package, which was discontinued, but `Pillow` is still developed, that's why the name is different when installing but import's are still like the old `PIL`

Answer (score 3):

Its called PIL:

```
from PIL import Image
```