# Installed Python Module Not Found on macOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-imaging-library

I know that this has been asked a number of times before, but none of the solutions I have found are working for me. I think my question is best explained by the below:

```
MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.1.1 
setuptools 40.8.0 
wheel      0.33.4 

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ pip3.7 install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/55/2ce41fa510f131c776112a1d24ee90cddffc96f1bf0311efb14fdd8ae877/Pillow-6.0.0-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-6.0.0

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
Pillow     6.0.0  
pip        19.1.1 
setuptools 40.8.0 
wheel      0.33.4 

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ python gps_exif.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps_exif.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Pillow import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ python --version
Python 3.7.3

MacBook-Pro-52:gps_meta_to_csv Thomas$ ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
PIL       __pycache__     pip       setuptools      wheel-0.33.4.dist-info
Pillow-6.0.0.dist-info    easy-install.pth    pip-19.1.1.dist-info    setuptools-40.8.0.dist-info
README.txt      easy_install.py     pkg_resources     wheel
```

How can I get this Pillow module to be seen by my Python script? Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971858/importerror-no-module-named-pillow)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+pillow+ImportError

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you'll notice when viewing the **[`Installation`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)** instructions is a large warning:

> <sub>**Pillow** and **PIL** cannot co-exist in the same environment. Before
>   installing **Pillow**, please uninstall **PIL**.</sub>

You appear to have `PIL` installed, so uninstall it first, then see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I am confused by this module, probably because Pillow is a fork of PIL. The doc for Pillow gives examples using PIL (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html), but as you point out, the two cannot exist together.

Comment: I don't need to use Pillow, but I read that PIL was being deprecated and so was trying to switch over.

Comment: Also, why doesn't PIL show up in the output of 'pip list'?

Comment: I definitely agree that it's confusing. What happens when you do `import PIL`? If `PIL` is not installed then `Pillow` should be able to use `PIL` as an alias. You could also try `import PIL as Pillow`.

Comment: `import PIL` works just fine. When I remove `PIL` from that `site-packages` directory,  `import PIL` fails and `import Pillow` still fails. I will try `import PIL as Pillow` tonight, but at that point aren't I just using `PIL` and not `Pillow`?

Comment: Well that’s the thing, you’ll need to determine which is actually installed. Try doing `import PIL; print(PIL.__file__)` to see where it’s location actually is perhaps. Also when you remove `PIL` from the site-packages directory try to then re-install `Pillow`.